# How to cite a paragraph that is copy and pasted from another source?

Tags: citations, quotation

I’m writing the master thesis, and I’d like to know if the following text would be appropriate or not. Consider the middle paragraph is copy-pasted from the source https://www.lipsum.com/

> In this section, I will briefly overview the Lipsum dummy texts and full details can
>   be found in the source [1].
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
>   five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>   remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
>   the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
>   more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
>   including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
>
> Bibliography: [1] Source, formatted in APA, IEEE, …

Comment: See [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/82975/11365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open with:

> In this section, I will briefly overview the Lipsum dummy texts and full details can be found in the source [1].

This suggests you are providing a brief overview, yet you follow with (what I presume is) a verbatim quote:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

I suggest revising your opening sentence (perhaps provide context and set the scene, then introduce the verbatim quote) 
 and indenting the quoted text, you can use  `\begin{quote}...\end{quote}` if you're using LaTeX.

---

Comment from the OP:

> So, as I see, using proper indentation and indexing to references is enough to quote a source?

Indentation is appropriate for long quotations, such as the example you provided. For shorter quotations, you can wrap a quote inside quotation marks (and follow with a citation), e.g., "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry" [1]. In both cases, a reference to the original source must be provided.

Comment: I get it. So, as I see, using proper indentation and indexing to references is enough to quote a source?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've edited my answer to add further details.

Answer (score 0):

You should more properly put the paragraph starting "Lorem Ipsum..." in quotes. It seems a bit long for a quote, but not obscenely so. I think the first couple of sentences of it are probably enough for your purposes and avoid any issues of over quoting and hence infringing of copyright.

Comment: That makes sense. Anyway, this was just a dummy example. Actually I'll probably need to make many of these quotations, so would it be better to just put them between quotation marks, or summarize them with my own words, and keep quoting the source?

Comment: You can do either, but you need to cite in any case. Minimizing quotations to what is actually needed is a pretty good strategy. Generally you need to cite whether you quote or paraphrase to avoid plagiarism issues. One reason to paraphrase is to avoid over-quoting.

Comment: So if my paraphrasing won't make any better, is it better to just quote it as it is?

Comment: That's a judgement call, I think. Just make it clear that the underlying ideas come from the source, not yourself.